# setState not updating text on screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The text on my screen is not updating from the initial text even though I called the setState method

```
String? _currentAddress = 'Fetching current location...';

....

_getAddressFromLaLo() async {
try {
  List<Placemark> placeMarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
      _currentPosition!.latitude, _currentPosition!.longitude);

  Placemark place = placeMarks[0];
  setState(() {
    _currentAddress =
        "${place.locality},${place.postalCode},${place.street},${place.name},${place.subLocality}";
  });
} catch (e) {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.toString());
}
}

....

Text(
      _currentAddress!,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

Links for reference:
https://github.com/ahkharsha/pregAthI/blob/main/lib/widgets/home/insta_share/insta_share.dart

Comment: Reference you provide is not working, could you share working one.

Comment: where is _currentAddress declared?

Comment: I edited the reference link now..

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the future in the `setState`:

```dart
 _getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      final position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
              forceAndroidLocationManager: true);
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
        // ...
        await _getAddressFromLaLo(); // <-- added `await` here 
      });
    } catch (_) { /* ... */ }  
  }
```

Comment: Its still not working...

Comment: I looked through your code and you're showing the address in the `modalBottomSheet` while `setState`ing the widget. You need to either show `_currentAddress` in your stateful widget, or move your modal bottom sheet widget to a stateful widget and `setState` there.